# create a customer programmatically magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer

How to create a new customer programmatically? i want to set new custom attributes and set the group id according to some condition but i don't know what to put here : setFirstname($POST['name_input_firstname'])??? and same for last name?.
Here is my simple code not all :

```
class CreateCustomer  extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;
    private $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory
     */
    protected $customerFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
     */

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    )
    {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        {
            // Get Website ID
            $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();

            // Instantiate object (this is the most important part)
            $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
            if (isset($_POST['contact_person'])) {
                $customer->setGroupId(4);

                // Preparing data for new customer
                $customer->setEmail($_POST['email']);
                $customer->setFirstname($_POST['???']);
                $customer->setLastname(???);
                $customer->setPassword(??);
                $customer->.....


            }
            // Save data
            $customer->save();
            //$customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
        }
    }
}
```

so how to do that and thanks in advance

Comment: Can you specify your requirement, So I can give you answer according to that? Does your requirement is to set custom attribute value after customer registration?

Comment: no i want to set new attributes and the other attributes (first name, ... email...) and group_id when registrating with code  becuase i have 2 form and a differentes attributs

Comment: do you get all required fields value, at place where you do this code like firstname, email etc?

Answer (score 0):

**inject in constructor below**

\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory

**add this code in your method**

```
$store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
$websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
$customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
$customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)->setStore($store);
$customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
          ->setStore($store)
          ->setFirstname($firstname)
          ->setLastname($lastname)
          ->setEmail($emailAddress)
          ->setMobile($mobile)
          ->setPassword(rand());
$customer->save();
```

Comment: but $firstname and last name are not static i want to get them from form

Comment: Nauman  m. Mansuri  i added some new details about this here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248593/add-customer-programmatically-magento-2