# Add customer programmatically magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have added 3 new custom attributes(code client, Social status, web site) and i want to add a customer prgrammatically and also set the id group when registrating. how to do so and how to recuperate the input name of first name, last name and tel and how to set the new attributes because when i tried to setCodeClient() he did not know this setter please help me it's very important to me to know how to proceed and really thanks  for all of you

Comment: Where you call your custom code? Either Event Observer or Plugin or What? Share the code which you try for this.

Comment: in new module : i created 3 attributes via upgradedata then i created  another register form and now i want to  save the customer one with  specific group and specific attributs that are differents to the second form

Comment: But your requirement is to set custom attribute value, right?

Comment: i want t set the new attributes and  other attributs (email, lastname, first name , group_id..)

Comment: Look, the default fields like email, lastname, firstname must be set when you create customer, after creating you can set custom attribute value.

Comment: so the is no way to set all the attributs from controller ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85151/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-developper-magento).

Comment: because i have two forms and in the second form i have  to hide the name and last name and set them to any value manuually and not show them in form

Answer (score 0):

Update Custom Attributes by below code

Inject below in controller

> \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
>   \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $_storeManager

```
$custom = $this->customerFactory->create();
$custom = $custom->setWebsiteId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
$custom = $custom->loadByEmail($customerEmail);

$custom->setClientCode('code');
$custom->setSocialStatus('status');
$custom->setWebsite('website_id');


// Main code to resolve this issue.
$customerData = $custom->getDataModel();
$customerData->setCustomAttribute('client_code', 'code');
$customerData->setCustomAttribute('social_status', 'status');
$customerData->setCustomAttribute('website', 'website_id');

$custom->updateData($customerData);
$custom->save();
```

Comment: what is the ('code') becuase i want to recuperate the value of code from the form (the value that customer has added )

Comment: what is ($customerEmail) ???

Comment: $customerEmail =  Customer's email which you want to update.

Comment: '"code" means the actual value that you want to insert.

Comment: but   iw ant to recuperate them from form

Comment: now that i created  new contoller how to change the action of the form to point on the new controller

Comment: you need to override that form into you THEME and Then can change the Action.

Comment: yes i overrided the form 2

Comment: but how to call the new actionn

Comment: i added a new  function public function getFormAction()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('newcust/index/index') ;
    }
and called it in the form 2 action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction() ?>"

Comment: but not saving the custome